Deliver KDB keys for IBM MQ, based only on certificates
Is it possible for IBM MQ to deliver KDB keys, based only on certificates, without providing KDB file?

No.   For recent versions of MQ you can use either CMS keystore (kdb files) or PKCS12 keystores.  For Java applications you can use PKCS12 or Java Key store (jks files).  For managed .NET you use the windows key store.

Thanks! What do you suggest if I want to use it in .NET, but for both Windows and Linux?

Look at this blog that describes both:  https://community.ibm.com/community/user/integration/blogs/ram-subba-rao-chalamalasetti/2024/02/15/tlsssl-configuration-for-a-mq-net-application-on-l?CommunityKey=183ec850-4947-49c8-9a2e-8e7c7fc46c64
